# Logic - paraphrase propositions with negations to no negations

Tags: logic

How do I paraphrase a proposition with a negation to not have a negation?
I am thinking about this proposition

[image]

Comment: There exists at least one positive square-root-free real number.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: A paraphrase without an explicit negation

Answer (score 1):

From :

> $\lnot (\forall x \exists y (x >0 \Rightarrow x = y^2))$

by the equivalences of $\lnot \forall$ with $\exists \lnot$ and of $\lnot \exists$ with $\forall \lnot$, we get :

> $\exists x \forall y \lnot (x >0 \Rightarrow x = y^2)$.

Now, we exploit the equivalence between $P \rightarrow Q$ and $\lnot P \lor Q$ to have :

> $\exists x \forall y \lnot (\lnot x >0 \lor x = y^2)$.

Now, we apply De Morgan : $\lnot (P \lor Q)$ is equivalent to $\lnot P \land \lnot Q$ to have :

> $\exists x \forall y (x >0 \land x \ne y^2)$.

---

For more readibility, we can rewrite it as :

> $\exists x (x >0 \land \forall y (x \ne y^2))$.

Comment: Then the statement isn't true anymore. But why must x not equal y^2?

Comment: @Hodhod: You are taking a negation on a statement which is true. Why do you expect the result to be true?

Comment: @Hodhod - The original sentences was : "for all real x, **if** x is positive, **then** it has a square root", which is true. Thus, its negation : "there is a real which is positive and has **no** sqaure root" must be false ...

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Let $P$ be some property of a variable $z$, and let $A$ and $B$ be statements.

- $$\neg [\forall z, P(z)] \iff \exists z :\neg P(z)$$
- $$\neg [\exists z :P(z)] \iff \forall z, \neg P(z)$$
- $$\neg[A \implies B] \iff A \land (\neg B)$$

Comment: Still has a negation...

Comment: I was hoping that the OP could negate $x=y^2$ (By no means is this a complete answer).

Comment: i was going to answer with these hints myself, this is the best answer so far @HennoBrandsma

Comment: When I've to paraphrase it do I've to look at the whole statement including x > 0 -> x = y^2?

Comment: yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: can you please explain it with words? it still has a negation

Answer (score 0):

The statement after the negation says, that all positive reals are squares of a real.
So the negation says that there exists some real $>0$ that is not the square of a real. But this still has the negation in it, namely in "not equal", e.g. we can say $$\exists x\in \mathbb{R} \forall y \in \mathbb{R}: (x > 0 \land \lnot(x = y^2))$$

Comment: Doesn't the statement after the negation say, that all reals are squares of a real? How can paraphrase the statement so it doesn't have any negation at all?

Comment: All positive reals, yes. I don't know. I don't think negation can be easily avoided.

Answer (score 0):

$\lnot (\forall x \in X \,\, (BLAH))$ is equivalent to $\exists x \in X \,  (\lnot \, BLAH)$

$\lnot (\exists x \in X \,\, (SNERD))$ is equivalent to $\forall x \in X \, (\lnot \, SNERD)$

$\lnot( (BLAH) \implies (SNERD))$ is equivalent to $(BLAH) \, AND \, (\lnot \, SNERD)$

Comment: I am still new in new in this subject :-) What are BLAH and SNERD?

Comment: They are any mathematical statements or mathematical properties, what other answers refer to using more pedestrian symbols such as $P$.